# Sql query to find everything about the students who are not registered in a particular class

Tags: sql, ms-access

Suppose I have three tables Student, Class, Student_Class(linking table).

```
Table:Student
Student_ID
FirstName
LastName

Table:Class
Class_ID
Class_name

Table:Student_Class (Linking Table)
StudentClass_ID
Class_ID
Student_ID
```

Given a particular Class_ID, I want to know everything about the students who are not registered for that particular class.

I tried the following but it does not work. Lets say I try for class id = 3

```
SELECT DISTINCT Student.* 
FROM Student 
INNER JOIN Student_Class 
    ON Student.Student_ID = Student_Class.Student_ID 
WHERE ((NOT (Student_Class.Class_ID)= 3))
```

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `MS Access`?  They are *not* the same thing.

Comment: I am using MS-Accesss

Answer (score 1):

## Flow

1. Match all student and all classes

```
Student INNER JOIN Student_Class ON (Student.Student_ID = Student_Class.Student_ID)
```

2. Reject Students in particular class (Example 3)

```
(Student_Class.Class_ID <> 3)
```

## Query:

```
SELECT Student.* 
  FROM Student INNER JOIN Student_Class 
    ON (Student.Student_ID = Student_Class.Student_ID)
 WHERE (Student_Class.Class_ID <> 3);
```

## In order to get all Students that they are not in any Class, please try below:

```
SELECT Student.*
  FROM
       (
        SELECT Student.*
             , Student_Class.Class_ID
          FROM Student LEFT JOIN Student_Class ON Student.Student_ID = Student_Class.Student_ID
         WHERE ((Student_Class.Class_ID <> 3) OR (Student_Class.Class_ID IS NULL))
        ) Student LEFT JOIN Class ON Student.Class_ID = Class.Class_ID
;
```

## Data:

[image]

## Result:

[image]

Comment: What if a student has not registered for *any* class at all?  This wouldn't capture any student that wasn't in the `Student_Class` table.

Comment: @Siyual

I do not know can use Left Join in MS Access.
But it is similar I think:

<pre><code>
SELECT Student.* 
  FROM Student LEFT JOIN Student_Class 
       ON (Student.Student_ID = Student_Class.Student_ID)
       Student_Class INNER JOIN Class
       ON (Student_Class.Class_ID = Class.Class_ID)
 WHERE (Student_Class.Class_ID <> 3)
;
</code></pre>

Comment: tried this. Did not work. Shows me the students who are taking the class 3 which is what I do not want. This could be because these same students might be taking a class 4 and that class 4 is linked with these students in the linking table. Hence it shows them.

Comment: @HarisGhauri

I updated code, please look above to see all input and output:

This is final query:

SELECT Student.*
  FROM
       (
        SELECT Student.*
             , Student_Class.Class_ID
          FROM Student LEFT JOIN Student_Class ON Student.Student_ID = Student_Class.Student_ID
         WHERE ((Student_Class.Class_ID &lt;&gt; 3) OR (Student_Class.Class_ID IS NULL))
        ) Student LEFT JOIN Class ON Student.Class_ID = Class.Class_ID
;

Comment: @NgocNam did you change your last answer to the final query?

Comment: Student does not have a column class id? Where did that come from in your query?

Comment: @HarisGhauri

First, did that query run well?

Explain: 
+ I updated query.
+ There are sub-query with alias is Student, it has Class_ID. They are same name, but extend columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118047/discussion-between-haris-ghauri-and-ngoc-nam).

Comment: @HarisGhauri, really really sorry, I did not know I got a new message from you.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will show all student that did not attend 1 or more classes, including the class name.

```
SELECT Student.Student_ID, Student.FirstName, Student.LastName, 
Class.Class_ID, Class.Class_name
FROM Class, Student
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT *
FROM Student_Class
WHERE Student_Class.Student_ID = Student.Student_ID AND   
Student_Class.Class_ID = Class.Class_ID
```

)